# Double Pointer Error : incompatible types in assignment of ‘int*’ to ‘int [rows]’

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, double-pointer

I have a 2-D array (named 'c'). I am trying to create an array of pointers 'a' such that each cell in 'a' has the corresponding address of the zeroeth element of the respective row in c.

For Ex: a[0] contains the address of the zeroeth element of row c[0], a[1] contains the address of the zeroeth element of row c[1], and so on.

Furthermore, the variable 'b' is a double pointer that contains the address to the zeroeth element of the array 'a'.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rows, cols;
    cout << "Enter rows ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Enter cols";
    cin >> cols;

    int c[rows][cols]; // or int *c = new int[rows][cols]
    int(*a)[rows] = { NULL };
    int **b = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << "Enter data element [" << i << "][" << j << "]";
            cin >> c[i][j];
        }

        a[i] = &(c[i][0]);
    }

    b = a; // a, being an array stores the address of it's zeroeth element 
           // and hence can be assigned to b
}
```

But, I get the error:-  error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int*’ to ‘int [rows]’. Could you please help me understand if there is a gap in my understanding . Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just want to point out that that array C is just an array of pointers (that each point to the first element(int) in another array(the row)). So array A is just going to end up being the same array as C if you get it to work like you described.

Comment: `int c[rows][cols]` is not valid C++, this is a GCC extension (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html). Also, `int (*a)[rows]= {NULL}` is probably not what you think it is.

Comment: `int *a[size]` is an array of `int*`, `int (*a)[size]` is a pointer to one array of `int` (and the initializer `{NULL}` is equivalent to using `NULL`).

Comment: One does not simply assign arrays. There is evil there that does not sleep. Can I recommend [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)? it behaves more like what you seem to desire.

Comment: This is sounding more and more like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)